# From horizontal drag to vertical drag

Tags: jquery

source: https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView

live view: http://thegrubbsian.github.io/jquery.ganttView/example/index.html

How can I vertically drag items?

I tried to edit line 302 of the jquery.ganttView.js file from `axis: "y"` to `axis: "x"`  and I succeeded but when I release the element it returns to the origin point.

Edit:

callback function to modify:

```
function updateDataAndPosition(div, block, cellWidth, startDate) {
            var container = jQuery("div.ganttview-slide-container", div);
            var scroll = container.scrollLeft();
            var offset = block.offset().left - container.offset().left - 1 + scroll;
            
            // Set new start date
            var daysFromStart = Math.round(offset / cellWidth);
            var newStart = startDate.clone().addDays(daysFromStart);
            block.data("block-data").start = newStart;

            // Set new end date
            var width = block.outerWidth();
            var numberOfDays = Math.round(width / cellWidth) - 1;
            block.data("block-data").end = newStart.clone().addDays(numberOfDays);
            jQuery("div.ganttview-block-text", block).text(numberOfDays + 1);
            
            // Remove top and left properties to avoid incorrect block positioning,
            // set position to relative to keep blocks relative to scrollbar when scrolling
            block.css("top", "").css("left", "")
                .css("position", "relative").css("margin-left", offset + "px");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `axis` param is not enough. You have to modify the callback function (`updateDataAndPosition`) for vertical drag behavior. This function handle the logic and updating UI.

Comment: thank you so much

I edited the question by inserting the function to modify, could you tell me how to modify it?